# Are calculated values used in ORDER BY ever recalculated during sorting?

Tags: mysql, caching, sorting, sql-order-by

Suppose we have a query that orders by a calculated value that is *not* selected, for example:

```
select * from table
order by col1 * col2 - col3
```

During typical sorting operations in most languages, it is common for the sort value to be used multiple times during the sort, as a given record is compared to potentially many other records. It is possible that mysql has such an implementation.

Can anyone say *definitively* if mysql calculates such values *once* per row and stores them temporarily while the sort completes, or if the values are recalculated whenever a comparison is made (which may be 1-n times)?

I have tagged this mysql, but I would welcome comments/answers regarding/including other popular databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the answer is... mysql executes the calculation **once** per row.

Due to lack of credible answers, I ran a definitive [test on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/152a0/2) that orders by the result of a `not deterministic` function (that must be called every time it's compared) that also records in another table when it has been called. It shows that the number of times called = number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

I just used the MySQL query browser to explain a query with sorting on a calculation of several columns and it said that it used file sort...So it would appear that it uses a temporary index (calculate one time).

If you have a particular example that you wanted to test - you could make sure that it did the same for you.

Here is a link to one of the developer's blogs that details how order by works:

http://s.petrunia.net/blog/?p=24

Comment: "it would appear" isn't definitive (as my answer is), but it's close and since you're the only other answerer, you get the bonus :)